# Spring data MongoDB geospatial

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, geospatial

I need help.
Here my json stored in MongoDB

```
{
"forecastTime":3,
 "infos": [
   {
    "location": {
       "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": [ -10, 10 ] 
    },
    "data" : {
       "heading": 136,
       "wind": [
         {
           "sail" : "spi",
             "speed" : 8.56
            },
         {
           "sail" : "foc",
             "speed" : 12.34
         }
        ]
    }
  },{
    "location": {
       "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": [ -20, 10 ] 
    },
    "data" : {
       "heading": 78,
       "wind": [
         {
           "sail" : "spi",
             "speed" : 2.23
            },
         {
           "sail" : "foc",
             "speed" : 2.34
         }
        ]
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking for the query will retrieve the wind's speed for spi sail with forecast 3 (hours) and for the location at -20 & 10.
So, What will the best solution to do this ?

Thanks

I try with this function but I go no result

```
    public GeoResults<Wind> getWinds(float lon, float lat, int forecast) {

        Point point = new Point(lon, lat);
        NearQuery geoNear = NearQuery.near(point, Metrics.KILOMETERS).maxDistance(0.01);

        Query query = new Query(
            Criteria.where("forecastTime").is(forecast)
            //.and("type").is(type)
        );

        query.fields()
            .include("data.wind")
        ;

        geoNear.query(query);

        GeoResults<Wind> data = mongoTemplate.geoNear(geoNear, Wind.class);

        return data;
}
```

Finally, this sample code works

```
    // the query object
    Criteria findForecastCriteria = Criteria.where("forecastTime").is(forecast);
    // the field object
    Criteria findLocationCriteria = Criteria.where("infos").elemMatch(Criteria.where("location.coordinates").is(new double[]{lon, lat}));

    BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(findForecastCriteria.getCriteriaObject(), findLocationCriteria.getCriteriaObject());
    query.fields().include("data.wind");

    Grib g = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Grib.class);

    result = new ApiResult(
            lon
            , lat
            , g.getData().get(0).getWind().getSpeed()
        );
```

Comment: do you use spring data repositories or mongotemplate?

Comment: Your choice is mine ... it's a micro-service, i'll choose the one who can answer to my question :)

Comment: What have you tried? Also consider do you mean "near" or "exactly" in terms of the `"location.coordinates"`. Since "exact" does not require a geospatial query at all, and is simply a query parameter referencing the "exact" array. You only need a "geospatial query" for things that are either "near" given coordinates or "contained" within a bounding shape of coordinates.

Comment: Any short code to submit ? Thanks Neil for your note about geospatial query. Indeed, I'll use it to get interpolated winds later ...

Comment: @anthony44 . Do understand this is not a competition where you are host and others are participants. :) We are happy to help if you have any issues. But you should give it a try first yourself.

Comment: Apologize, it was not my goal ... come back soon with a big and concrete issue